# Python/Masonite: pymysql.err.OperationalError (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.1' (using password: YES)")

Tags: python, mysql, masonite

Have attempted several tutorials but encounter error after error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have permission to connect to your database using root from 172.18.0.1?

Try running `SHOW GRANTS` on your database to see if you have the correct permissions set at a database level:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root';
```

You may also want to double check the `.env` file in the root of your Masonite directory. This is where your environment is defined. `config/database.py` uses the environmental variables you define in `.env` to configure access to your database (below is the default sqlite configuration).

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=masonite
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_LOG=True
```